# How to put three or more images at navbar-right (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a navbar with Bootstrap, the problem is when I try to put two or more images in the right navigation bar, the height of the bar increases how can i fix it? Thanks!!

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="http://www.youtube.es/"><img src="IMAGENES/youtube.png"/></li> 
    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.es/"><img src="IMAGENES/twitter.png"/></li> 
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.es/"><img src="IMAGENES/facebook.png"/></li>   
  </ul>
```

Comment: Set width for images and use height as auto in css itself

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RxguB/64/)**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header pull-left"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">xxx</a>

        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="http://www.youtube.es/"><img src="IMAGENES/youtube.png"/></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.twitter.es/"><img src="IMAGENES/twitter.png"/></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.facebook.es/"><img src="IMAGENES/facebook.png"/></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

You didn't closed `<a>` tags .. Check all the tags were closed properly or not..

Comment: Ohhhh you saved me!!! i didnt close <a> tag thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!